# X and Y axis labels are not shown using android widget

Tags: androidplot

I want to use androidplot to show a plot inside an android widget. Actually, the main content of the widget is supposed to show the plot. My problem is that I don't see the x- and y- tic-labels at all. (I can set and see the overall range label like "temperature in °C", though).

Here are the relevant code parts (actually in Kotlin and not in Java):

```
val plot = XYPlot(context, "Historyplot")

plot.setRangeLabel("Temp. in Grad")
plot.setDomainLabel("Zeit")

plot.title.labelPaint.textSize = 20f
plot.rangeTitle.labelPaint.textSize = 20f
plot.domainTitle.labelPaint.textSize = 20f

plot.legend.isVisible = false

plot.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)

val h = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId).getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_HEIGHT)
val w = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId).getInt(AppWidgetManager.OPTION_APPWIDGET_MAX_WIDTH)
plot.setPlotMargins(10f, 10f, 10f, 10f)

plot.layout(0, 0, w, h)

val history = mutableListOf<Double>()

for (dataPoint in sensorHist) {    
    history.add(dataPoint.value ?: Double.NaN)
}

val series = SimpleXYSeries(history, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "")
val seriesFormat = LineAndPointFormatter(Color.BLACK, Color.BLACK, Color.LTGRAY, null)
plot.addSeries(series, seriesFormat)

val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

plot.draw(Canvas(bitmap))
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.plot_widget_img, bitmap)
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
```

And this is what it currently looks like (including two other widget elements in the top left and top right of the widget):
[image: widget screenshot]

I've tried many different things to make the tic-labels visible but none of them worked (`setRangeOriginLinePaint(Color.BLACK), series.useImplicitXVals(),  setLineLabelEdges(), setRangeStep(), setDomainStep(), setLinesPerRangeLabel()`, ...)

Could it be that x- any y-tics do not work in an android widget? Or am I missing something?

**Update**

Thanks, @Nick, I've added the line

```
plot.graph().setLineLabelEdges(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT, XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM)
```

and this is how it looks like (I've added red arrows as a visual guide):

[image: some labels visible]

A step in the right direction! How can I now manipulate the font style and, more importantly, that the whole labels are visible? I've tried `plot.layoutManager.addToTop()` but could only find the title of x and y and not the labels itself.

Comment: for clarity could you add a screenshot if what the graph currently looks like?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a response to your question update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the labels to display in the DemoApp's (very outdated) widget example by adding this:

```
plot.getGraph().setLineLabelEdges(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT, XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM);
```

It's not pretty but it's a start:

[image]

I see you already tried this but so far as I can tell, that's all you are missing.

**Response to your Update**

You can adjust positioning and color of your labels like this:

```
plot.getGraph().setLineLabelEdges(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT, XYGraphWidget.Edge.BOTTOM);
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelInsets().setLeft(PixelUtils.dpToPix(16));
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelInsets().setBottom(PixelUtils.dpToPix(4));
plot.getGraph().getLineLabelStyle(XYGraphWidget.Edge.LEFT).getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
```

produces:

[image]

After that its a matter of adjusting plot / graph margins etc.

Comment: Thanks, this worked pretty well! A side question: Is it possible to have the tic labels outside the plot?

Comment: yep it is.  you'll want to ask a separate question for that though, to avoid angering the SOF gods.

Comment: I already figured it out by changing the padding(s) and moving the lineLabelInsets.